# How to use excel rows as an input for python?

Tags: python

Instead of typing input every time and getting results from the python script, How to use a list of excel rows as the input to python code and export it to excel again.

For eg, my python script will do an operation on the given input and I have a list of inputs in an excel sheet.

```
*< some python codes >* 

**text = input("Type here - ")**  

*< some python codes >*
```

The result should take inputs from `"row 1, column 1"` from excel sheet, then process my code, then print the result in `"row 1, column 2"`.

loop

The result should take inputs from "row 2, column 1" from excel sheet, then process my code, then print the result in "row 2, column 2".

if it returns none for any input, it should print `"0"`

Comment: What have you tried? Please share your effort.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [xlwings](https://www.xlwings.org/).

Here's an example:

```
import xlwings as xw

wb = xw.Book('path_to_your_workbook.xlsm')
sht = wb.sheets['your_sheet_name']

# reading values
value1 = sht.range(8, 2).value
value2 = sht.range(7, 11).value

# changing values
value1 = value1 * 2
value2 = value2 + 3

# writing values
sht.range(8, 2).value = value1
sht.range(7, 11).value = value2
```